# Mandar variable a otra función Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

cuando cargo la cargo en un input el `tipo->id` que tiene el cliente. Entonces para saber ese valor utilizo el `onload`.

```
window.onload=muestraMas;
    function muestraMas() {
        var idDireccion=document.getElementById('direccion').value;
        var tipoCliente=document.getElementById('tipoCliente').value;

        actualizarTotales(tipoCliente);  //Aquí envio lo que recibo a la función actualizarTotales

        .... //aquí tengo una función ajax según lo que traigo en idDireccion//
    };
```

Luego tengo una función `keyup` que según los valores que voy poniendo en unos inputs, hago que realice cálculos. Entonces es a esta función a la que me quiero llevar el `tipo->id` por que según que tipo tengo que hacer unos cálculos u otros.

```
function actualizarTotales(envio, tipoCliente){  //Aquí paso como parametro el envio y tipoCliente, "envio lo paso para otra cosa"
        var tabla = $('#tabla');
        var subtotal = 0;
        var iva = 0;
        var total = 0;
        $(tabla).find('.eSubTotal').each(function(index, value){
          var valor = $(value).val();
          if( !isNaN(parseFloat(valor))){ // NaN = Not a number
            subtotal += parseFloat(valor);
          }
        });
        
        var nuevoEnvio = envio * 100/100;
        console.log(tipoCliente); //Aquí hago un console.log haber que me llega..
        console.log(nuevoEnvio);
        
        iva = (subtotal+nuevoEnvio)* 21/100;
        total = subtotal + iva + nuevoEnvio;

        //console.log(nuevoTotal);
        $('#subtotal').val(Math.round(subtotal * 100) / 100);
        $('#iva').val(Math.round(iva * 100) / 100);
        $('#total').val(Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
    }
```

Al cargar la página me devuelve `undefined` y si actualizo valores por keyup, también me devuelve `undefined`.

Alguna sugerencia de como hacer esto??

Answer (score 0):

revisa los parametros

```
actualizarTotales(tipoCliente); //<--
```

La función esta definida para recibir 2 párametros

```
function actualizarTotales(envio, tipoCliente)
```